# Can keys be configured individually with Filterkeys in Microsoft Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, filterkeys

Can keys be configured individually with Filterkeys in Microsoft Windows 7?

I.e., if I set the repeat rate to 0.5 second, this applies for all keys by default: I don't want to slow down the repeat rate for arrow keys or backspace.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As natively supplied in Windows 7, Filter keys apply to all keys, not for individual keys.  Source: My own Windows 7 machine and verify the settings